# Substitute for the .delay() function for jQuery 1.3 and making a jQuery loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a substitute for the .delay() function in jQuery 1.3? I know in jQuery 1.4 you can simply use the .delay() function to delay a function from taking place for X amount of seconds but is there someway I can do the same thing but in 1.3?

Also I need to make a looped function in jQuery so after the function has been executed, it will execute again. Is there any possible way of doing this in jQuery 1.3?

I'm stuck in jQuery 1.3 and in my predicament I cannot update to 1.4 so please do not answer by telling me to update unless that is my only option here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your question right, but setTimeout function don't resolve?

```
function delay()
{
     setTimeout("Func1()", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can copy the function from the jquery 1.4+ source into your code by adding the following to your script:

```
// the direct source of the delay function in 1.4+
jQuery.fn.extend({
    delay: function( time, type ) {
        time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
        type = type || "fx";

        return this.queue( type, function() {
            var elem = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
            }, time );
        });
    }
});
```

then call the .delay function normally.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this problem and i advice you to use the setTimeOut function of javascript itself. It's not a better alternative, but it is very good also.

**For loop Function**
Write a function for example

```
function runThisAgainAndAgain(){
   call this same function in setTimeout here....
}
```